# Why doesn't my suspension fork rebound after being compressed?

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, suspension

I use a RockShox SID suspension. After using it for a while I noticed the suspension has not been rising back out on its own. I have to lift the front fork of the bike for the suspension to go back to its resting form. I would appreciate if anybody could tell me what's wrong with my suspension and how I could fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Either the air spring is too weak or there is something causing resistance to movement in the fork. First thing to do is check the air spring pressure. Can you pease edit your question to include how old or well-used the fork is.

Comment: What do you mean by well-used?

Comment: is it new, a few years old, have you ridden in a few 100kms or a few 1000?

Comment: it was my dad's bike for a few years and he just recently gave it to me, I believe its at least 4-5 years old.

Comment: He usually rides the bike on the road so it doesn't really involve the suspension so when i started using it the suspension became tight and I tried adjusting the PSI in the suspension but it didnt work.

Comment: If the air spring pressure is in spec, and *stays* in spec while riding, I would guess a seal is leaking or a valve is blocked. A service and fluid change is likely the only way to get it working properly again.

Comment: When was the fork last serviced, if ever?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have debries blocking the valve at the rebound chamber. Even if you have no air pressure in the chamber(that means 1 atm) it should still have enough force rise back again after being compressed.

I for once bought a "White Brothers DH-2" which was mainteined recently, or that's what they told me. One day it got compressed all the way(15cm+3cm kit) and got stuck. I opened the tubes very carefully, you know because springs. The "mechanich" sleeved the springs in a piece of rubber(in fact was a cuted out wheel tube) and with friction pieces started to come apart and made it's way to the rebound chamber, forming a plug.

Cleaned it up good, lubed up the seals and changed the oil. Stuff felt like new afterwards.

Comment: my suspension doesn't really have the rebound knob in a different colour and when I tried turning where the arrow is pointing at, it does not feel different

Comment: @zadsnek My man, you should take it appart or get it to a shop. A tip if you go DYI, taking apart the rebound part is nasty disassemble it in a container, paper towels will certianly help. Some times it might enviromental debries, other times is stuff from the guts, which is a good reason to take a look inside. If you find a stack of washer leave them alone.

Answer (score 0):

Alan spokes I used to work for gt bikes all there suspension bikes came with rocks standard which were guaranteed for life try that AVE your local friendly bike shop might be able to help you need to find your nearest outlet for rocks and enquirs

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Does "AVE" mean "avenue?"  It would help make your posts more clear if you tried to avoid abbreviations, and used punctuation.  (Not to sound like grammar police, just trying to help you make your answer as good as possible.)